# 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'System'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, data-binding

I have this issue to bind gridview, It is working at first time with no error on paging or delete case it will shows the error, your help me to save my time

```
DataBinding: '<>f__AnonymousType5`3[[System.Int32, mscorlib, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],
[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a
```

This is my data binding code

```
var objBanner = from obj in dataContext.tbl_achevements
                        orderby obj.ID descending
                        select new
                        {
                            obj.ID,
                            obj.v_Year,
                            obj.Achivement
                        };

        if (objBanner.Count() > 0)
        {
            lblMsg.Visible = false;
            lblMsg.Text = "";
            grdDetails.DataSource = objBanner;
            grdDetails.DataBind();
        }
```

This is Stack Trace:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not 
contain a property with the name 'System'.]
System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String propName) 
+12225118
System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Object container, String[] expressionParts) 
+142
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField.GetValue(Control controlContainer) 
+164
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField.OnDataBindField(Object sender, 
EventArgs e) +71
 System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +304
System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +12450431
System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +321
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 
dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, 
Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, 
TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +295
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable 
dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)
```

Comment: If anything, that DataBind error is not caused by the code you show. There must be another place in your code path that sets a Grid to a datasource that is a DataTable

Comment: @rene m not able to understand what you are trying to say can you please elaborate more